# How can I install multi-architecture packages on RHEL 8

Tags: rhel, package-management, arm, cross-compilation

On an x86_64 Ubuntu 20.04 system, after some minor modifications under `/etc/apt` and running `dpkg --add-architecture s390x`, I can install the `foo-dev:s390x` package and the `gcc-8-s390x-linux-gnu` package and then I can cross-compile software against the `foo-dev` package. Ditto the `arm64`, `ppc64le`, etc. architectures. The binaries I built can be taken over to an Ubuntu 20.04 platform on the other architecture and they run as expected.

Given that RHEL 8 runs on those architectures as well, I'd expect that I could do the same. It certainly appears to be a multiarch capable OS. For instance, there are both 32-bit and 64-bit x86 packages for, say `openssl-devel`:

```
openssl-devel.x86_64 : Files for development of applications which will use OpenSSL
openssl-devel.i686 : Files for development of applications which will use OpenSSL
```

And they can be installed simultaneously. So I'd hoped that it would be as easy as `yum install openssl-devel.arm64` or similar.

But after quite some time searching, I've been unable to figure out what I need to do to allow installation of the development packages or cross-compiler for `s390x`, `ppc6el4`, `arm64`, etc. on RHEL 8.

Is this possible? Is there some documentation which explains how to do the necessary repository configuration to enable these other architectures as development targets? Can someone provide the necessary `yum`/`dnf`/`rpm` or related commands to enable package installation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RPM has a concept of “compatible” architectures, which is what allows you to install `i686` packages on an `x86_64` system. But it doesn’t cover foreign architectures or allow you to cross-compile beyond what’s supported by `gcc -m`.

However it is possible to build packages for foreign architectures, using `qemu-user-static` and `mock`: prepare your source RPM, then build it [using `mock`, specifying the architecture](https://rpm-software-management.github.io/mock/Feature-forcearch):

```
mock -r fedora-35-aarch64 package.src.rpm
```

`mock` will detect that it needs to use emulation, and will use QEMU to handle the chroot. This will typically be slower than cross-compilation, but you won’t run into issues with host v. target binaries.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After building from the sprm under qemu, would I then be able to install the produced foreign architecture RPM on the x86 RHEL system? That would let me build out the cross-compilation environment package by package, which is better than nothing. I'd still need to bring my own cross-compiler, it seems, but that's a lot better. Actually running the tasks I want under qemu isn't an option: the hope here was to get more performance by being able to do foreign architecture builds on more accessible and resource heavy x86_64 systems.

Comment: No, that won’t be possible; as I tried to explain in the first paragraph of my answer, you can’t install foreign (non-“compatible”) packages on x86.

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying. I must say that it is a very disappointing result. I'm honestly shocked that RHEL can't do this.

Comment: I did have a bit of a crazy idea about how to achieve what I want. I'm wondering if I could use your `qemu` driven process to produce the packages from `srpm`s, and then, again with a `qemu` `chroot`, actually install them, and then do some sort of overlay mount to make the files appear in the right places in the base OS. Then, assuming a bring-your-own cross compiler had the right sysroot-y idea of things, maybe it could work? It sounds rather complex though. I'm genuinely puzzled why RHEL doesn't allow this. It seems utterly harmless to allow the installation of hw-incompatible libraries.